# Powershell simple regex capture group not capturing

Tags: regex, powershell

I seam to be having the hardest times with this simple regex in powershell. I want to capture the `(\d+)` group of this simple match expression :

```
$myvar = ([regex]'<element attr="(\d+)">').Matches('<element attr="1">')
```

The problem is that `$myvar[1]` is not defined no matter what I try.

When I run this regex in sublime text replace tool it captures the group correctly.

What am doing wrong in this simple script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$myvar` is a collection of Match objects. There's only one match, so `$myvar[0]` is the first Match object.

From there you can access `.Captures` or `.Groups` to get your capture group.

It would be `$myvar[0].Captures[0].Value` or `$myvar[0].Groups[1].Value`, depending on how you want to refer to it.

Comment: Thank  it works now. The wired thing is that i tried `$myvar.Groups[1]` and it is not defined. I was miss leaded beacause the output of `>$myvar` is the same as `>$myvar[0]`   (They both contained Groups member). Do you know why the output is the same for `$myvar` and `$myvar[0]`?

Comment: Because when you display an array of something, it displays all of its items. There's only one item in the array, so that's all you see.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to use callbacks in a replacement I'd recommend using [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) or the [`-match` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) instead of a `regex` object.

```
PS> $m = '<element attr="1">' | Select-String '<element attr="(\d+)">'
PS> $m.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
1
```

```
PS> '<element attr="1">' -match '<element attr="(\d+)">'
True
PS> $matches[1]
1
```

Comment: Agreed; they are much nicer to use.